# appending ->where() clauses based on conditionals

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, fluent

I want to append `where` clauses to the query based on certain conditions, the problem is that the way I check if it returned a row from the database it always returns true.

If I do a query in one line like so:

```
$test= DB::table('users')->where('email', $email)->where('password', $password)->first();
```

It works as expected, if a row is found it is true and vice versa, but if I append to the query like so, it is always true (which makes sense, but how do I check that it actually returned something from the db?):

```
$test= DB::table('users');
$test->where('email', $email);
 $test->where('password', $password);
$test->first();

if ($test) {
       // always true
 }
```

Comment: What exactly does `$test` contain in the case when it's empty?

Comment: @Don'tPanic nice one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `$test->first();` executes the query and returns the first result, but you aren't assigning that result to anything, so `$test` is still just the query object, which will always evaluate to `true` as you are seeing. If you assign it to something else and then check that, it should work.

```
$example = $test->first();

if ($example) { ...
```